# How to access web-application deployed on one laptop using Bluetooth of different mobile without using Internet?

Tags: java

I want to access the web-application front end which is deployed on one laptop from different mobile using Bluetooth.

I made simple login authentication Form and I deployed this on one laptop . Now I want to hit the URL and see the login page on my mobile 
and able to do database authentication using mobile ,for this purpose I don't want to used Internet or LAN or WIFI . I want to used Bluetooth of both devices for access..!

Comment: please anybody reply yar....!